# MSVC++ how to ouput something to the "output"-window during compilation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

sometimes i see that certain projects write something to the output during compilation.

how can that be achieved in MSVC++

thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `#pragma message` e.g.

```
#define MESSAGE(t) message(__FILE__ "(" STRINGXXX(__LINE__) ") : " t)
#define STRINGXXX(x) STRINGYYY(x)
#define STRINGYYY(x) #x
```

then if you put

```
#pragma MESSAGE("TODO: testing")
```

it will appear as a clickable message just like the normal compiler messages

Comment: Why STRINGXXX and STRINGYYY instead of just one macro?

Comment: __LINE__ is a number and it needs to be transformed into a string. You use another macro in order to avoid having the string "__LINE__" all over the place.

Comment: You can also use _CRT_STRINGIZE defined in crtdefs.h so you only need to define the macro MESSAGE

Answer (score 6):

You want to include something like this in your source code:

```
#pragma message("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [#pragma message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dkzch2%28VS.80%29.aspx) in one of your source files to output a string when that file is preprocessed.

Also, when a custom, pre- or post- build step is executed, the "description" field is echoed to standard output.

Answer (score 1):

As Timo Geusch said: the `#pragma message` directive is used for that.

As an exotic side effect of template metaprogramming, it's also possible to use the compiler as a calculator :)

```
template<int i> struct Message;

template<int i> struct Fac {
   static const int v = i * Fac< i-1 >::v; 
};

template<> struct Fac<1> { static const int v = 1; };

Message< Fac<10>::v > m;
```

will result in the output message

```
Line 10: error: aggregate 'Message<3628800> m' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```