# How do I output a compile-time numeric constant during compilation in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compile-time, compile-time-constant

Visual C++ has `#pragma message` that [outputs a string into compiler output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1177159/57428). Now I have a factory:

```
template<class Type>
CComPtr<Type> CreateComObject()
{
   CComPtr<Type> newObject( new CComObject<Type> );
   //do some tuning to the object
   return newObject;
}
```

and I want to output the size of class that is passed to `new` (namely `sizeof( CComObject<Type> )` into the compiler output. Looks like `#pragma message` only accepts strings.

How can I output a compile-time numeric constant?

Comment: I don't have VC at hand, but for GNU and clang, a simple `std::enable_if_t<false,char[sizeof(CComObject<Type>)]>` does the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then I think you can do this:

```
template<size_t size> 
struct overflow{ operator char() { return size + 256; } }; //always overflow
//if you doubt, you can use UCHAR_MAX +1 instead of 256, to ensure overflow.

template<class Type>
CComPtr<Type> CreateComObject()
{
   CComPtr<Type> newObject( new CComObject<Type> );
   char(overflow<sizeof(CComObject<Type>)>());
   return newObject;
}
```

The value of `sizeof(CComObject<Type>)` will be printed as warning messages during compilation.

---

See this small demo : http://www.ideone.com/Diiqy

Look at these messages (from the above link):

> prog.cpp: In member function
>   ‘overflow::operator char() [with
>   unsigned int **size = 4u**]’:
>   prog.cpp: In
>   member function
>   ‘overflow::operator char() [with
>   unsigned int **size = 12u**]’:
>   prog.cpp:
>   In member function
>   ‘overflow::operator char() [with
>   unsigned int **size = 400u**]’:

In Visual Studio, you can see these messages in the *Build Output* tab; it may not appear in *Error List > Warnings* tab.

---

The idea is taken from my another solution:

[Calculating and printing factorial at compile time in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977715/calculating-and-printing-factorial-at-compile-time-in-c/4977816#4977816)

Comment: @Nawaz, +1 good answer, But will it give compilation warning consistently for all compilers ? (can't it be an error or ignored message for any other compiler ?)

Comment: @iammilind: Since the overflow is guaranteed, then all decent compiles will generate these warning messages (in my opinion).

Comment: It need not overflow, if `char` is more than eight bits large.  And neither gcc nor Cormeau's online compiler provide these warnings.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: The maximum value of `char` can be 255 which is defined by the Standard itself. So it will overflow. (Or if you're not satisfied, you can use `UCHAR_MAX +1` instead of the magic number `256`).

Comment: @Nawaz : The maximum value of `char` is definitely not defined by the standard, only the size is (`1`).

Comment: @ildjarn: Its defined by the C Standard. And C++ follows it.

Comment: @Nawaz : No, the C standard says that the value is "*equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign*", so the maximum value of `char` is *at least* `255`, not exactly `255`.

Comment: @ildjarn: If that is so (though I've to see it again),  then `UCHAR_MAX +1` can ensure the overflow.